# Wavefunction in different basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction

Suppose I have some wavefunction $|\psi\rangle$, and I want to represent this in two different  basis $|x\rangle$ and $|u\rangle$. I know that $u=g(x)$.

Anyway, I know that the representation of the wavefunction in $|x\rangle$ is given by $\psi(x)=\langle x|\psi\rangle.$

Similarly, in the $|u\rangle$ basis, the representation is $\langle u|\psi\rangle.$

Moreover, $$\langle u|\psi\rangle=\int dx\langle u|x\rangle\langle x|\psi\rangle=\int dx \langle u|x\rangle\psi(x)$$

My question is more to do with notational misunderstanding. For example, is $\langle u|\psi\rangle = \psi(u) ?$ Or should we rather say, it is some other function $\phi(u)$ ? After all, in the $u$ basis, it would have a different functional form. However, we can agree that the abstract form of the wavefunction remains the same.

This can be interpreted as, in the $u$ basis, $|\psi\rangle$ has the functional representation $\phi(u)$. In the $x$ basis, it has the functional representation $\psi(x)$, where $\phi$ and $\psi$ are different functions.

Since $u=g(x)$, we can say $\phi(u)=\phi(g(x))=f(x)=\psi(x)$. Thus one can say, $\psi() = \phi\space o\space g()$. Thus $\psi(x)=\phi(u)$.

Hence, $$\phi(u)=\langle u|\psi\rangle = \psi(x) = \langle x|\psi\rangle$$

---

However, there seems to be another approach to the problem of representation in a different basis. This alternate method gives us a slightly different outcome.

Remember, $u=g(x)$, thus ,

$$\int|x\rangle\langle x|dx=\int|x\rangle\langle x|\frac{du}{g'(x)}=\int|x\rangle\langle x|h(u)du=\int|u\rangle\langle u|du=\hat{1}$$

So, we have $$|u\rangle=\sqrt{h(u)}|x\rangle$$

We have normalized our new basis kets with respect to the old basis, which was already normalized.

Thus, $$\psi(x)=\langle x|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{h(u)}}\langle u|\psi\rangle=\langle u|\phi\rangle=\phi(u)=\psi(g^{-1}(u))$$

Even here we have $\psi(x)=\phi(u)$.

However, instead of : $$\langle u|\psi\rangle = \langle x|\psi\rangle$$,

we have instead : $$\langle u|\phi\rangle = \langle x|\psi\rangle$$

But this seems to suggest that the abstract wavefunction itself has changed, as we moved from one basis to another. In the first method, this wasn't the case.

This shows : $$|\phi\rangle = \sqrt{h(u)}|\psi\rangle$$

What does this represent exactly, and how do I interpret this? In the previous case, we had the same abstract ket having two different functional forms in two different representations. Here, we have managed to create this new ket vector, that is related to the old one. Does this new ket vector even have any meaning at all ?

In this alternate approach $\psi(x)=\langle x|\psi\rangle$. However $\phi(u)=\langle u|\phi\rangle \ne \langle u|\psi\rangle$.

What is $|\phi\rangle$, and what does $\langle u\phi\rangle$ mean here then ?

Any interpretation or help regarding where I went wrong would be highly appreciated.

EDIT :

This question is not related to the linked [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/673818/300178), which was resolved in the comments. It is on the same topic, but I believe it is a completely different question. That question was how to perform a change of basis in integration form. In this question, I've done so, in two different ways, and came across seeming conflicting answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change of Basis in quantum mechanics using Bra-Ket notation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/673818/)

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I think this question should be closed now. During the period that it was closed, others have answered this, under other questions. So, it is somewhat pointless to reopen this question now.