# Change of basis in bra-ket notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, notation, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

In the post [Change of Basis in quantum mechanics using Bra-Ket notation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/673818/change-of-basis-in-quantum-mechanics-using-bra-ket-notation) , the accepted answer explores the relationship between an arbitrary operator $\hat{x}$ and another named $\hat{u}$, such that $\hat{x}^3 \equiv \hat{u}$. The answer argues that
$$\hat{1} |\psi \rangle=\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} dx |x\rangle \langle x | \psi \rangle, \ u=x^3$$
Using $u=x^3$, we can say $dx = \frac{1}{3u^{2/3}}$, and $u^{1/3}=x$. As such, the author of the accepted answer concludes that
$$\hat{1} |\psi \rangle=|\psi \rangle=\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{3u^{2/3}})du |u^{1/3}\rangle \langle u^{1/3} | \psi \rangle$$
This, however, does not actually change the variables, as I understand it. The author themself points out that we've merely rewritten $\hat{1} |\psi \rangle$. How can we change the $|u^{1/3}\rangle \langle u^{1/3} | \psi \rangle$ in our integral to be simply $|u \rangle \langle u | \psi \rangle$

Comment: (1/1) There were a whole sequence of questions from that poster that I engaged with. Perhaps [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/679981/83835) will be helpful; in particular see the section "New representations of the same state". By writing $|x\rangle = |u^{1/3}\rangle$, we're just recognizing that we can relabel the state, but in the integral, the substitution pulls out some extra factors. In the linked post, I attached those extra factors to the integration measure. But you can *also* renormalize the state by writing$$| u\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}u^{1/3}} |u^{1/3}\rangle\,.$$

Comment: (2/2) in which case we have$$|\psi\rangle =  \int du\,|u\rangle\langle u| \psi\rangle\,. $$ One of the things to realize about this special case is that $\hat{u}$ and $\hat{x}$ are diagonalized by the same basis, and so it all comes down to how we want to represent the resolution of the identity and whether we want to renormalize the states so that the extra factors disappear or if we want to keep them in explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State vectors in quantum mechanics are transformed via some unitary operator, for example, $|\psi\rangle_{new}=U|\psi\rangle_{old}$. Since the action of a linear operator on a state vector is enirely characterized by its action on the basis vectors, i.e. $|y^j\rangle=U|x^j\rangle$, we use the completeness relation to express the arbitrary state ket as:
$$|\psi\rangle=\int dj\;|x^j\rangle\langle x^j|\psi\rangle.$$
We can find the genralized Fourrier cofficient for $\psi$, in the new basis $|y^k\rangle$, by taking the inner product:
$$\langle y^k|\psi\rangle=\int dj\; \langle y^k|x^j\rangle\langle x^j|\psi\rangle.$$ Using the unitary operator to relate the basis,
$$\langle y^k|\psi\rangle=\int dj\; \langle x^k|U^{\dagger}|x^j\rangle\langle x^j|\psi\rangle,$$
where $\langle x^k|U^{\dagger}|x^j\rangle$ are the matrix elements of the unitary transformation in the old basis.

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much this is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Very well explained too. Just one really really quick follow up, if you don't mind -- why do we use $U^{\dagger}$ in the last step instead of just $U$?

Comment: @JBatswani Because we have taken the inner product with the *bra* $\langle y^k|$, if $|y^k\rangle=U|x^k\rangle$, then $\langle y^k|=(U|x^k\rangle)^{\dagger}=\langle x^k|U^{\dagger}$.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

A generic quantum state, $|\psi\rangle$ can be expanded in terms of any complete set of eigenstates. If $|u\rangle$ are the eigenstates of an observable $\hat u$, then one can use the completeness of the eigenstates to expand the operator thus,$$|\psi\rangle=\int du\;|u\rangle\langle u|\psi\rangle.$$ Where as noted above, the states $|u\rangle$ are eigenstates such that:
$$\hat u|u\rangle=u|u\rangle$$
Now the case in your post is an actual "change of variables", the computation above is not a change of variables. For example, given a state expanded in the position space; changing the state to momentum space is not a change of variables, it is a change of *basis*. The computation of concern in your post appears to be a mere change of variables as opposed to an actual change of basis despite its appearance.

Comment: That's exactly my question. I understand that my calculations are merely a change of variables as opposed to a change of basis. How would I actually do a change of basis? How is a change of basis done in bra-ket notation? How does one change bases from position space to momentum space?

Comment: @JBatswani The momentum and coordinate spaces are linked through a Fourier transformation - for the general case, you need to find a transformation matrix or operator that relates the two bases you want (some $M$ so that $|u\rangle = M|x\rangle$). A concise reference would be Sakurai's text (see the first chapter).

Comment: @ShKol This makes sense. In my example where $\hat{u}=\hat{x}^3$, how would I find my matrix?

Comment: @JBatswani An operator isn't the same as a ket/bra. So, while the operator equation your example uses is sensible, it does not hold in a ket form (kets are vectors, what is a vector cubed?). A change of basis involves changing the kets you use in a specific problem - not the operators (which do look different, but only because of the change in representation). So, both $\hat{u}$ and $\hat{x}$ have the same diagonal basis (as mentioned in the answer you linked).

Comment: First change basis, and then express the operator in the new basis via a similarity transformation: $\hat X^{\prime}=U^{\dagger}\hat XU$.